# Unexpected behavior w/ sum() function

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm trying to compute the column sums of a `47 x 3` normalized design matrix, `X`, with the following code:

```
sum(X)
```

Here's `X`'s content:

```
X =

   1.0000e+00   1.3001e-01  -2.2368e-01
   1.0000e+00  -5.0419e-01  -2.2368e-01
   1.0000e+00   5.0248e-01  -2.2368e-01
   1.0000e+00  -7.3572e-01  -1.5378e+00
   1.0000e+00   1.2575e+00   1.0904e+00
   1.0000e+00  -1.9732e-02   1.0904e+00
   1.0000e+00  -5.8724e-01  -2.2368e-01
   1.0000e+00  -7.2188e-01  -2.2368e-01
   1.0000e+00  -7.8102e-01  -2.2368e-01
   1.0000e+00  -6.3757e-01  -2.2368e-01
   1.0000e+00  -7.6357e-02   1.0904e+00
   1.0000e+00  -8.5674e-04  -2.2368e-01
   1.0000e+00  -1.3927e-01  -2.2368e-01
   1.0000e+00   3.1173e+00   2.4045e+00
   1.0000e+00  -9.2196e-01  -2.2368e-01
   1.0000e+00   3.7664e-01   1.0904e+00
   1.0000e+00  -8.5652e-01  -1.5378e+00
   1.0000e+00  -9.6222e-01  -2.2368e-01
   1.0000e+00   7.6547e-01   1.0904e+00
   1.0000e+00   1.2965e+00   1.0904e+00
   1.0000e+00  -2.9405e-01  -2.2368e-01
   1.0000e+00  -1.4179e-01  -1.5378e+00
   1.0000e+00  -4.9916e-01  -2.2368e-01
   1.0000e+00  -4.8673e-02   1.0904e+00
   1.0000e+00   2.3774e+00  -2.2368e-01
   1.0000e+00  -1.1334e+00  -2.2368e-01
   1.0000e+00  -6.8287e-01  -2.2368e-01
   1.0000e+00   6.6103e-01  -2.2368e-01
   1.0000e+00   2.5081e-01  -2.2368e-01
   1.0000e+00   8.0070e-01  -2.2368e-01
   1.0000e+00  -2.0345e-01  -1.5378e+00
   1.0000e+00  -1.2592e+00  -2.8519e+00
   1.0000e+00   4.9477e-02   1.0904e+00
   1.0000e+00   1.4299e+00  -2.2368e-01
   1.0000e+00  -2.3868e-01   1.0904e+00
   1.0000e+00  -7.0930e-01  -2.2368e-01
   1.0000e+00  -9.5845e-01  -2.2368e-01
   1.0000e+00   1.6524e-01   1.0904e+00
   1.0000e+00   2.7864e+00   1.0904e+00
   1.0000e+00   2.0299e-01   1.0904e+00
   1.0000e+00  -4.2366e-01  -1.5378e+00
   1.0000e+00   2.9863e-01  -2.2368e-01
   1.0000e+00   7.1262e-01   1.0904e+00
   1.0000e+00  -1.0075e+00  -2.2368e-01
   1.0000e+00  -1.4454e+00  -1.5378e+00
   1.0000e+00  -1.8709e-01   1.0904e+00
   1.0000e+00  -1.0037e+00  -2.2368e-01
```

And the sum:

```
ans =

       4.7000e+01   1.0885e-15   1.2684e-14
```

The sum for column 1 is correct, but the others are way off. Any thoughts?

Comment: what do you expect the answer for the second two columns to be?

Comment: i get: `47.000000000000000   0.000188260000001  -0.000599999999999`

Comment: They are correctly evaluated in mine. Which version is yours?

Comment: @petrichor: I'm using Octave 3.2.4

Comment: Hmm, I don't have Octave installed on my machine. Best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Columns 2 and 3 look like they're summing approximately to zero.  Each element is a floating point value, and sometimes you lose some precision when adding and subtracting floats.  Rather than seeing a zero, you're just seeing a really tiny number (10^-15!).  An easy work-around would be to set all numbers below some threshold to zero:

```
mysum = sum(X);
mysum(mysum < 1e-12) = 0

ans = 

47.0000   0   0
```